# Clipping with grid and naming layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip

I have created a regular (nominally square) grid using Create grid and can clip points and lines within each grid square using the Clip tool. So now I have 168 layers called Clipped. I'd like to give each layer a unique name (e.g. Cliiped1, Clipped2, ..., Clipped168 will do!).

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to rename your loaded layers, you could use something like the following in the **Python Console**:

```
x = 0
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    x = x + 1
    layer.setLayerName('Clipped' + str(x))
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]